# LED blink & delay period

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I want to change LED blinking pattern and delay period using serial monitor in Arduino.

- first pattern: 1 LED moves sideway
- second pattern: 2 LED moves sideway
- third pattern: 3 LED moves sideway
- fourth pattern: 4 LED moves sideway
- period 1: 500 ms
- period 2: 300 ms
- period 3: 100 ms
- period 4: 50 ms

When I enter a, b, c, d, change LED pattern.
If I enter c when pattern a is in progress, but it will be proceeded with two leads added on the spot.
And I want when I enter 1, 2, 3, 4, delay period is changed.

Next, I've made as many codes as I can, but I don't think I can do it anymore, so I'm posting a question.

```
char pattern[4][8] = {
  {0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80},
  {0x03, 0x06, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x30, 0x60, 0xC0, 0x81},
  {0x07, 0x0E, 0x1C, 0x38, 0x70, 0xE0, 0xC1, 0x83},
  {0x0F, 0x1E, 0x3C, 0x78, 0xF0, 0xE1, 0xC3, 0x87}
  };

char data = ' ';
char count = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  for(int i=14; i<21; i++) pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{

  if(Serial.available()>0)
  {
    data = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(data);
    switch(data)
    {
      case 'a':
      {
        for(int i=count; i<7; i++) digitalWrite(i+14, pattern[1][count] & 1<<i);
        count++;
        if(count==7) count = 0;
        delay(100);
        if(data == !'a')
        {
          break;
        }
      }
      case 'b':
      {
        for(int i=count; i<7; i++) digitalWrite(i+14, pattern[2][count] & 1<<i);
        count++;
        if(count==7) count = 0;
        delay(500);
        if(data == !'b')
        {
          break;
        }
      }
      case 'c':
      {
        for(int i=0; i<7; i++) digitalWrite(i+14, pattern[3][count] & 1<<i);
        count++;
        if(count==7) count = 0;
        delay(500);
        if(data == !'c')
        {
          break;
        }
      }
      case 'd':
      {
        for(int i=0; i<7; i++) digitalWrite(i+14, pattern[4][count] & 1<<i);
        count++;
        if(count==7) count = 0;
        delay(500);
        if(data == !'d')
        {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: From the look of it, this is for an Arduino, right? I took the liberty to [edit] your question to add that as a tag. If it's not right, then please [edit] your question to update the tags appropriately.

Comment: I am not completely sure if I understand the question. The LED patterns are already working fine, is this correct? And you want to add the possibility to change the delay? Or are there things I am missing here?

Comment: code is not working. And i want to add the possibility to change the delay.

Comment: Can you describe what is not working?

Comment: LEDs turn on likes randomly

Comment: "_so I'm posting a question._" What **is** the question? Please read [ask] and update your question to include a clear question. I already helped a bit with the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several small errors in your code that I try to explain to you step by step. The finished code can be tested (and visualized) [here](https://wokwi.com/projects/344046684366438995).

```
for(int i=14; i<21; i++) pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
```

Here you only initialize 7 out of 8 pins. You need to change `i<21` to `i<=21` or `i<22`. You can count them if you want: `14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20` would be the case for `i<21`, but those are only 7 pins.

```
for(int i=count; i<7; i++) digitalWrite(i+14, pattern[1][count] & 1<<i);
```

You want to set all 8 LEDs, so you need to initialize `i` to `0` and count to `i<8` or `i<=7`. Also you start with `pattern[1]`, the first pattern needs to have the address `pattern[0]`.

```
    if(count==7) count = 0;
```

Same thing here, if you want to have all 8 cases, you need to count from 0 to 7. If you reset `count` at 7, you won't have the last LED state. Change it to `count==8`.

```
if(data == !'a')
{
    break;
}
```

Don't put your break into a condition, simply use `break` without `if`.

```
if(Serial.available()>0)
...
    switch()
```

You want to change the LEDs on every iteration of `loop()`. If your switch is inside `if(Serial.available()>0)`, you only change your LED states when a serial message arrives. This is the reason your LEDs change "randomly". They only get an update, if you actively send a message, not cyclically.

I would recommend to use a variable for `delay` and move it outside the switch, same goes with `if(count==8) count = 0`.

The final code would be this:

```
char pattern[4][8] = {
  {0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80},
  {0x03, 0x06, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x30, 0x60, 0xC0, 0x81},
  {0x07, 0x0E, 0x1C, 0x38, 0x70, 0xE0, 0xC1, 0x83},
  {0x0F, 0x1E, 0x3C, 0x78, 0xF0, 0xE1, 0xC3, 0x87}
  };

char data = ' ';
char count = 0;
int mode = 0;
int delayTime = 500;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Start application");
  for(int i=14; i<22; i++) pinMode(i, OUTPUT); //Initialize all 8 pins
}

void loop() 
{
  if(Serial.available()>0) //Get's only executed if a serial message arrives
  {
    data = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(data);
    switch (data) {
      case 'a': mode = 0; break;
      case 'b': mode = 1; break;
      case 'c': mode = 2; break;
      case 'd': mode = 3; break;
      case '1': delayTime = 500; break;
      case '2': delayTime = 250; break;
      case '3': delayTime = 100; break;
      case '4': delayTime = 50; break;

      default: break;
    }
  }

  switch(mode) //Get's executed on every call of loop()
  {
    case 0:
      for(int i=0; i<8; i++) digitalWrite(i+14, pattern[0][count] & 1<<i);
      break;
    case 1:
      for(int i=0; i<8; i++) digitalWrite(i+14, pattern[1][count] & 1<<i);
      break;
    case 2:
      for(int i=0; i<8; i++) digitalWrite(i+14, pattern[2][count] & 1<<i);
      break;
    case 3:
      for(int i=0; i<8; i++) digitalWrite(i+14, pattern[3][count] & 1<<i);
      break;
  }
  delay(delayTime); //Always wait for delayTime ms
  count++;
  if(count==8) count = 0; //Reset count if it is >7
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. I hasn't been long since I started learning coding, so there were many parts that I lacked. it helped me a lot.